# Converting a local folder structure to a folder structure on a server

Tags: c#, asp.net, path, iis-express, .net

I'm currently playing around with Paths in .Net and have run into some difficultly with regards to replicating a local folder structure passed as a string from a web service to my site running under localhost on IIS Express.

Essentially, our users will select an image within our desktop software, the local path of which will be sent as a property of the image in our web service. So, when my script accesses the web service, it is fed a string such as:

```
C:\\Users\\axumadmin\\Pictures\\axumImages\\Countries\\Canada\\canadianFlag.jpg
```

What our users will then do is FTP this folder structure to a specified directory on our server:

```
ServerRoot\\umbraco\\axumImages\\Countries\\Canada\\canadianFlag.jpg
```

The main issue I have here is that I cannot seem to modify the path retreived from the web service to only return the directories from axumImages downwards. So in essence, my local path would be converted to:

```
axumImages\\Countries\\Canada\\canadianFlag.jpg
```

I have already tried playing with System.IO.Path to convert this path into the format that I wish to be returned but ultimately all I have acheived so far is either retreiving just the image filename:

```
canadianFlag.jpg
System.IO.Path.GetFileName(image.FileName);
```

or the parent directory of the image

```
C:\\Users\\axumadmin\\Pictures\\axumImages\\Countries\\Canada
```

Therefore my question is, how can I parse the string so that it is only using axumImages and its descendants?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what have you tried so far? will users *always* be uploading from `C:\\Users\\<username>\\Pictures`?

Comment: I've mentioned above. I've tried variations of the methods provided in System.IO.Path. My next step was trying to look at how string parsing is handled in C# so that I could parse the string and retreive everything after and including axumImages\\

Comment: string test = image.FileName.Split(new[] { "axumImages" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `string.Substring`

```
var startIndex = image.FileName.IndexOf("axumImages");   
string test = image.FileName.Substring(startIndex, image.FileName.Length-startIndex)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this in the end using string parsing.

```
string test = image.FileName.Split(new[] { "axumImages" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
```

In this example, image.Filename is my filename. So if the filename is:

```
C:\\Users\\axumadmin\\Pictures\\axumImages\\Countries\\Canada\\canadianFlag.jpg
```

this will return

```
\\Countries\\Canada\\canadianFlag.jpg
```

I can then concatenate this into a usable variable below which then amounts to the path I require:

```
var actualPath = "axumImages" + "test";
```

Comment: That works sure but this is probably cleaner and better for next time:

`var startIndex = image.FileName.IndexOf("axumImages");   string test = image.FileName.Substring(startIndex, image.FileName.Length-startIndex)`

Comment: Why is this cleaner and better? You're talking to Javascript developer here who's learning C# and .Net as he goes along :-)

Comment: `Split` is used when you want to break a string into a number of *tokens* (eg getting individual fields from a CSV file) - Substring should be used when you want a substring of the string, ie your exact case and you would not have to add the `axumImages` string back on again at the end like in your code

Comment: Nice. Thanks for letting me know. If you add this as an answer I'll mark it as correct :-)